# How should negative assumption questions be handled?

Tags: discussion

If anyone asks a question in which they assume a negative thing, should it be closed?

Comment: What do you mean by "negative thing" exactly? Can you include some examples? Because otherwise its pretty obvious if it gets nasty, it will be closed eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it depends how sincere the question is, but mostly, if it is on topic it shouldn't be close. We should point out negative assumption either in comments, or if question permits, in the answer. I also think closing such questions might make Muslims/Islam look intolerant and close-minded, therefore, I think we should be tolerant, and open-minded even when question is aggressive.

Comment: I agree with you +1